# Dispatch redux action in callback

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I have started working with redux in react-native and I encountered problem, when I am `dispatching` action in `onLoadStart` function for Image component, the callback is firing and I see that action is called and I see `Loading...` on screen, but when I am `dispatching` in `onLoadEnd` function nothing happen`(callback loadEnd is not fired, app looks like frozen)`. When I use console.log in both places code is working fine. Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
 class DisplayImage extends Component {

    loadStart() {
      this.props.iLoadingFunction(true);
    }
    loadEnd() {  // <- this function is not fired
      this.props.iLoadingFunction(false);
    }

    render() {
        if (this.props.isLoading) {
            return <Text>Loading…</Text>;
        }
        return (
          <View>
              <Image
                source={{uri: 'https://test.com/image'}}
                onLoadStart={this.loadStart.bind(this)}
                onLoadEnd={this.loadEnd.bind(this)}
               />
          </View>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        isLoading: state.isLoading
    };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return bindActionCreators({ iLoadingFunction }, dispatch);
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DisplayImage);
```

action and reducer

```
export function iLoadingFunction(bool) {
    return {
        type: 'IS_LOADING',
        isLoading: bool
    };
}

export function iLoadingFunction(state = false, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'IS_LOADING':
            return action.isLoading;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you checked case `IS_LOADING` is working properly?

Comment: I think your brackets are off. componentDidMount is enclosing the entire render function.  Also, you need to define those two methods outside componentDidMount, and then call them inside of it.

Comment: I removed componentDidMount, something goes wrong when I pasted code. I checked iLoadingFunction action and I see it is called also reducer is called, but the loadding... goes to infinity. 
When i replace action with console.log  loadStart() {
      console.log('start')
    }
    loadEnd() {  // <- this function is not fired
      console.log('stop')
    } stop is called without problem

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is coming from the order that actions and renders are occurring in.  Let's look at the `render` function:

```
render() {
    if (this.props.isLoading) {
        return <Text>Loading…</Text>;
    }
    return (
      <View>
          <Image
            source={{uri: 'https://test.com/image'}}
            onLoadStart={this.loadStart.bind(this)}
            onLoadEnd={this.loadEnd.bind(this)}
           />
      </View>
    );
}
```

The first time the component mounts `this.props.isLoading` is `false`, so the component renders

```
<View>
    <Image
      source={{uri: 'https://test.com/image'}}
      onLoadStart={this.loadStart.bind(this)}
      onLoadEnd={this.loadEnd.bind(this)}
     />
</View>
```

The `Image` mounts, begins loading the image and dispatches `this.props.iLoadingFunction(true)`.

At this point `isLoading` updates in the store are triggers a re-render of the component.  This time `this.props.isLoading` is true so the component renders

```
<Text>Loading…</Text>
```

Now the original `Image` has been removed from the hierarchy.  I'm not actually sure if it continues to download the image, but the `onLoadEnd` handler does not fire as the component expecting to handle it has been removed.

To get around this, I would leave the `Image` in the hierarchy and just include or exclude the `Text` based on `this.props.isLoading`, like so

```
render() {
    return (
      <View>
          { this.props.isLoading && <Text>Loading…</Text> }
          <Image
            source={{uri: 'https://test.com/image'}}
            onLoadStart={this.loadStart.bind(this)}
            onLoadEnd={this.loadEnd.bind(this)}
           />
      </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried you approach, but now there is infitite render, because when component props this.props.isLoading is true, then false component is rendering again, so  onLoadStart is fired again.

Comment: I'll be honest @mrc, I haven't done much react native, mostly standard react. In react, the virtual dom diffing algorithm would not touch the `Image` component and just insert and remove the `Text` node based on the `isLoading` flag. I assumed react native would do something similar. Perhaps I'm wrong?

Comment: I saw that  render function was called in loop. I used different solution. I created separate component for Loading and now only loading  listen for props isLoading changes, so Image is not rerendered anymore.

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer and accept it.  This will help other users when looking for help with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to use callbackable-actions standardized actions.
I recommend using the [redux-cool](https://github.com/Ruben-Arushanyan/redux-cool) package to do that

```sh
npm install redux-cool
```

```js
import {actionsCreator} from "redux-cool"
const callback = () => {
    console.log("Hello, I am callback!!!")
}
const callbackable_action = actionsCreator.CALLBACKABLE.EXAMPLE(1, 2, 3, callback)
console.log(callbackable_action)
//      {
//          type: "CALLBACKABLE/EXAMPLE",
//          args: [1, 2, 3],
//          cb: [[Function callback]],
//          _index: 1
//      }
callbackable_action.cb()
//      "Hello, I am callback!!!"
```

for more info, see: [Redux Cool](https://github.com/Ruben-Arushanyan/redux-cool)